# Symbolic links Cygwin vs. Msys2 vs. Win 10 (mklink)

Tags: cygwin, symlink, msys2, mklink, mobaxterm

I mean to create symbolic links in Msys2 from PortableApps, under Win 10
(I need portable applications to be able to carry the apps directory across systems), as I do in Linux.

For comparison, I will quote what I see with: 1) Msys2; and also other two options: 2) portable MobaXTerm (which is Cygwin based), 3) a (DOS) command prompt.

1. **Msys2**:
   I get the error `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'myfile': Operation not permitted`

   **EDIT** (I am not sure if there was any update in-between): now in Msys2 `ln -s myfile` does not report an error, but it copies the TARGET instead of creating a symbolic link. I do not know why the change in behavior, but this is also useless to me.
2. **MobaXTerm**:
   I can do `ln -s myfile` with no problem.
   But it is not a suitable workaround.
3. **Command prompt**:
   `mklink` creates a symbolic link.
   This might be a workaround, if I could launch it from msys2.
   But it requires admin rights, or at least [Developer mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development), and I would need something without this requirement.
   (I wonder what is MobaXTerm doing to overcome this requirement).
   See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/550732/use-mklink-in-msys)
4. (TBC: **Windows explorer**: did not test it).

**Why the difference?**

**Is there a way to create symlinks in Msys2 (with no admin)?** Perhaps by launching from msys2 a Cygwin process, which would of course require having some Cygwin application in the system (could the Cygwin dll alone be enouhg?)

*Related*:

https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/249

https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/41/

http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/symbolic-links-ln-s-command-td7159.html

https://www.joshkel.com/2018/01/18/symlinks-in-windows/

Comment: Usage: ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME

Comment: @Biswapriyo - It did not work, see updated OP.